# How do you display image from "image_url" in Yelp API?

Tags: json, uitableview, yelp

I now understand how to parse and display JSON data, but one thing eludes me: when I call "image_url" and receive the actual URL, how can I instead display the image that it refers to? ...and yes, I am a novice :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]]];
```

where `theUrl` is the url in string format. Then simply assign the image to your image view: `imageView.image = image` - presuming you have set up a UIImageView either in your code, as an IBOutlet or as a tagged object in a view.

**NOTE:** You may want to have a look at [Lazy Table Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) to load the image asynchronously.

Comment: Sorry, Patrick: one last. Would I be correct in saying I can get rid of all references to TableView since I am not using it? (obviously JSON and the other references need to stay).

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking, are you displaying a single image? If so, I guess you can! No harm in trying!

Comment: I did away with the TableView on this one View Controller that images are being called into via Yelp API, and it looks like everything is still fine. Cool stuff, I learned something today :)